# Properties of the Lebesgue Measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I had a few questions regarding some properties of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which I couldn't figure out.

1.) If $A \subset [0,1]$ is measurable such that $\mu(A) > 0$, then does there exist $x, y \in A$ such that $|xy|$ is irrational?

My thoughts: For $\mu(A)$ to be positive, $A$ has to contain uncountably many irrationals, as otherwise it would be countable and hence have measure zero. Intuitively, the answer to the above should then be yes as we have "enough" irrationals, but I'm unsure how to show this. For a given irrational $x \in A$, it would be enough to see that the set $\{y \in A : xy \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is countable, as we could then throw away this set, but I'm not confident this set is countable.

2.) If $B \subset [0,1]$ is non-measurable, define $C = B \times {0} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Can $C$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$B$ certainly is not closed, as closed sets are measurable. But not all closed sets on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the product of closed sets from $\mathbb{R}$.

3.) Does there exist a measure space $(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ such that there is no countable collection of measurable subsets $X_n$, all of finite measure, which cover $E$?

The only examples of measure spaces I've seen so far have been $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its subsets, but all of these spaces certainly have countable covers with finite measure, so I'm not sure where to look for such a space - or, how to prove the negative.

Thanks.

Comment: 2) If $C$ were closed, you would have $B$ is the inverse image of $C$ under $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2, x \mapsto (x, 0)$. 3) Try counting measure...

Comment: 1) If not, $A \times A \subseteq \{ (x, y) : |xy| \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ -- then what can you say about the product measure of the right hand side?

Comment: @DanielSchepler 1) I'm guessing the product measure on the RHS should be zero, but I'm not seeing why. I understand 2 and 3 now - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix any $x_0\in A, x_0\ne 0.$ Define $f:[0,1] \to [0,x_0]$ by $f(y) = x_0y.$ Then $f$ is injective on $[0,1].$ Since $\mu(A)>0,$ $A$ is uncountable. Hence $f(A)$ is uncountable. A moment's reflection then shows that $f(A)$ contains irrationals. Thus for some $y\in A,$ $f(y)$ is irrational. In other words $x_0y$ is irrational, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

A measure space that is the union of a countable sequence of finite-measure
subsets is called sigma-finite. As this property has a name, clearly there must be examples where it fails. A standard example is an uncountable set
with counting measure. But there are trivial examples, for instance
any nonempty set where we assign measure $\infty$ to each nonempty subset.